# How can I find out how many blocks are needed to download a game?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

When trying to see how many blocks a game is on the E-Shop, I find that the only way to view so is to have enough money to get that game.

For instance, in order to see how many blocks Bravely Default would take on my SD Card, I would need at least $39.99 to see how many blocks.

Problem is, I had this experience with my first downloaded E-Shop game and hated it.  I had $39.99 loaded up but after buying it I found out I did not have enough "blocks" on my SD Card.

I've tried looking at the "More Details" option when looking at a game, but there's nothing that would show how many blocks the game takes.

IS there any resource out there can show me how many blocks are in a game without having to have the required amount of money to get said game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://nintendoeverything.com/download-sizes-for-3ds-retail-games/
This is a list of most if not all 3ds titles and their download size.

Comment: The link you posted has 8 games.  I believe there are at least 50+ titles available on the eShop, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.